# Send keys when my windows keyboard is diffrent than the string language

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I would like to send email address using selenium to specific element, however my keyboard is configured to Hebrew while the string I trying to send is in English. this results with sending instead of "." a letter in hebrew "ץ"

```
uname = WebDriverWait(driver, web_driver_timeout).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, email_id))
)
uname.send_keys(username)
```

How can I force the sendkeys to ignore my windows keyboard configuration and to send the keys as is?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found alternative, at first find the current keyboard layout, and if it's Hebrew send SHIFT+ALT to switch back to English

```
def get_keyboard_layout_name():
  klid = ctypes.windll.user32.GetKeyboardLayout(0)
  buffer_size = 9  # Maximum size for the buffer
  buffer = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(buffer_size)
  ctypes.windll.user32.GetKeyboardLayoutNameW(buffer)

  if buffer.value == '00000409':
      return constants.keyboard_layout.ENG
  elif buffer.value == '0002040D':
      return constants.keyboard_layout.HEB
  else:
      print("Unknown keyboard layout")
      exit(-1)

def switch_keyboard_layout():
  # Pause for a moment before sending the keys
  time.sleep(2)

  # Send Alt+Shift
  pyautogui.hotkey('alt', 'shift')
```